# Can I apply for a US visa in Myanmar as an Indian citizen?

Tags: visas, usa, indian-citizens, residency, myanmar

I am a Indian passport holder. I am in Myanmar (Burma). Can I get a visa for the USA from here?

Comment: Downvoters, please add useful comments so that the new user understands what they need to change.

Comment: Rajeen, the web page of the US embassy in myanmar should contain this information.

Comment: I upvoted for the fact that I believe this to be a legit question. The US Embassy, as stated above, should have the information needed on whether or not you can obtain this visa.

Comment: @DCTLib and user79930 Actually, the US consulate probably won't give him much useful information.  I once asked a similar question from a US consulate, and they simply refused to say anything beyond "technically you may apply at *any* consulate in any country, but it may affect your chances of success".  They specifically refused to tell me in what circumstances it is acceptable to apply in a different country, and wouldn't even listen to my specific situation.

Comment: @user79930 This was very frustrating because I simply couldn't get enough information to decide whether it was worth taking the risk of applying elsewhere.  Later I learned that this is a typically American way of doing things.  The person I could talk to at the consulate through their help line would wash their hands of even the tiniest perceived responsibility.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [US State Department](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/tourism-visit/visitor.html):

> You must schedule an appointment for your visa interview, generally, at the U.S. Embassy or Consulate in the country where you live. **You may schedule your interview at any U.S. Embassy or Consulate, but be aware that it may be difficult to qualify for a visa outside of your place of permanent residence.**

So the answer is **yes**, you may apply for a visa. However be aware that unless you are resident in Myanmar it could be difficult for the US consulate there to assess your personal situation and therefore a rejection becomes much more likely. I'd advise you to either become a local resident before applying or to apply when back in India.

I would add that applying for a visa here in Prague I wasn't even asked to prove I'm a local resident. My work contract and my bank statement was all they've needed, however this was at one of the least busy US consulates in the world and my passport is from a country that is a VWP candidate. Applying at the Yangon consulate as a non-resident with little local ties could be a dangerous proposition.

In addition the US Consulate in Myanmar [states that](https://mm.usembassy.gov/visas/tourism-visit/how-to-apply/):

> All nonimmigrant visa applicants must show strong community, family, professional, and economic ties to Burma.

This shows that *by default*, they expect you to be a local.

P.S. There are situations where a particular US consulate routinely receives a lot of applications from neighboring countries because it's the closest consulate to where they live. In this case the consular employees would not be surprised to see documents from a third country and the above wouldn't apply.

Comment: I live in South of Brazil. Sometimes ago, the near Consulate in Brazil was São Paulo, almost 2000km. On the other hand, there is a Consulate in Montevideu (Capital of Uruguay). So, there were a bunch of people that got the Visa there without any problem.

Comment: Welcome! Brazil is a continental country! So, we have these kind of things here!

Answer (score 3):

You can apply for a visa in Burma, but at the visa interview, officers will want proof of ties to your country of residence, and if you don't live in Burma, you won't have Burmese documents proving ties.

US visa officers are mostly trained to deal with documents issued in the country where the embassy is located, so they may well not be familiar enough with Indian documents to be able to determine whether you have sufficient ties there and can safely be issued a visa.

So again, you can do it, but it's not recommended if you don't live in Burma.

Answer (score 3):

I once asked the same question from an American consulate, and the answer I got was (paraphrasing):

> You can apply anywhere, but applying in a different country than where you live may affect your chances of success.  I am sorry, I am not allowed to tell you more.

@JonathanReez's answer basically says the same. I wrote this answer to point out something else:

When I was given this answer, I found it very frustrating because of a cultural disconnect between how paperwork is done in many European countries vs the US.  I was used to relatively clear requirements: bring documents A, B, C and a notarized translation of D and you're good. (In practice: "You should've brought E too, in triplicate, and C doesn't have a stamp, so come back tomorrow".)

The American way of doing things is very different. There are not going to be very clear rules. You "just" need to convince the visa officer that you won't break the terms of the visa.  There is no clear set of requirements to satisfy to *guarantee* success, and you can never be certain about how exactly they will make their decision.  There is no rule such as "you can apply in country X if you present a residence permit for said country". Most of the responsibility stays with you, and if you are uncertain about how to fill out a form, or what documents to prepare, you won't get any help.  Consulate workers are not allowed to give you information that would create the appearance that they are helping you succeed with your application.

You will simply need to make your own judgement about whether the visa officer will find your reason for applying in Myanmar acceptable.