# Can I apply for USA visa from another country rather than my own

Tags: usa, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas, applications

I am an Indian studying in Belarus since 4 years can I apply for US  tourist Visa from belarus.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I apply for a US visa in Myanmar as an Indian citizen?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/106994/can-i-apply-for-a-us-visa-in-myanmar-as-an-indian-citizen)

Answer (score 4):

You can apply for a US nonimmigrant visa from any country, but for the best chance of approval you should apply from the country where you are currently resident. If you are now a long term resident of Belarus, then you should apply from Belarus.